# .NET forms authentication doesn't work

Tags: .net, vb.net, webforms, forms-authentication

I have an issue with my .NET application and it can only be reproduced sometimes and only on client's location, which makes it extremely difficult to resolve. In the application the forms authentication is used. There is a login page to which every anonymous user is redirected. After user enters username and password, it redirects to DefaultURL or some predefined page. The problem is that sometimes when user enters correct username and password, it doesn't login, instead it just refreshes the login page without any error messages. After several tries of inputing username and password, user is able to login to the system.

See my login page Submit_Click code below:

```
    Dim userName As String = tbUsername.Text
    Dim password As String = tbPassword.Text
    Dim returnUrl As String = Request("returnUrl")

    If IsValidated() Then
        FormsAuth.SignIn(userName, False)

        If password = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings("PasswordDefault") Then
            FlashMessage.ErrorMessage("You have default password """ & password & """. Please change it")
            Response.Redirect("~/ChangePassword.aspx")
        End If
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) Then
            Response.Redirect(returnUrl)
        Else
            If Roles.IsUserInRole(userName, Constants.SOME_ROLE) Then
                Response.Redirect("~/Forms/SomePage.aspx")
            Else
                Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx")
            End If
        End If
    Else

    End If
```

UPDATE:
I checked the windows Event Viewer and it has the following events:

> Event Type:    Information
>   Event Source:    ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0
>   Event Category:    Web Event
>   Event ID:    1315
>   Date:        4/29/2010
>   Time:        11:55:56 AM
>   User:        N/A
>   Computer:    TWDWEB1
>   Description:
>   Event code: 4006
>   Event message: Membership credential verification failed.
>   Event time: 4/29/2010 11:55:56 AM
>   Event time (UTC): 4/29/2010 3:55:56 PM
>   Event ID: 9e5aea5a6d6b4f7a96fc38a334d181dd
>   Event sequence: 26
>   Event occurrence: 4
>   Event detail code: 0
>
> Application information:
>      Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/Root/DataManipulationsService-1-129170192766483624
>      Trust level: Full
>      Application Virtual Path: /DataManipulationsService
>      Application Path: F:\Development\DataManipulationsService\
>      Machine name: TWDWEB1
>
> Process information:
>      Process ID: 7948
>      Process name: w3wp.exe
>      Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
>
> Request information:
>      Request URL:
>      Request path:
>      User host address:
>      User:
>      Is authenticated: False
>      Authentication Type:
>      Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
>
> Name to authenticate: xxxxxx
>
> Custom event details:
>
> For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "client location". Do you mean logging in from the client's machine (to the same web server as you would from any place else) or do you mean that they have their own copy of the website?

Without knowing the answer to that question, the first thing I would suggest is that if you're running from a web farm, you need to ensure that the `machineKey` element in the web.config file is set and is identical on each of the servers in the web farm.

Comment: By "client location" I mean the machine from which the request is made (in fact several machines). The server is the same, which means when I'm trying to reproduce this from my machine I use the same server as the client uses. I don't use web farm, just one instance of IIS with the app running. Does this give you any clues on what could happen? Thanks.

Comment: You can use something like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to look at the requests/responses to see what is different between your machine and the machine that is having the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Add a try/catch block around the signin() call. If that call is failing due to some misconfiguration on your client's system, you can expose the error to the user or log. Perhaps is the code doing any exception handling that could be burying the error?

Comment: The problem is that it happens only sometimes. I think in case of misconfiguration it should give an error each time. The thing is that sometimes it allows for login, and sometimes user can't login, but after entering username and password several times it logs in.